# Remove action from WC Vendor

Tags: php, wordpress, action, callable

I want to remove fields from user profile which are added by WC Vendor.
Of course I can do it in .php file but, after plugin update my changes will be lost.

**WC Vendor adds profile fields by this:**

`add_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( $this, 'show_extra_profile_fields' ) );`

`$this` is a instance to class which are created from main WC Vendor .php `new WCV_Admin_Users;`

So I think that handle to this instance get lost.

**Question:**

- It is any possible way to remove this action?

Comment: If you ask Google "WordPress Remove Action", you'll find this is the first result: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action and this is the second: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_actions

Comment: @cale_b remove_all_actions remove ALL actions, with other fields. I dont think that is a good idea...